# Firefox immediate crash

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I have a PC almost 10 years old, with windows XP in dual boot with Lubuntu 16.10, and although it was always up to date, some months ago firefox stopped to open correctly and when it opened it was impossible to use the firefox’s sync feature.
Than the crashes are the only thing that happens: I launch firefox, from desktop or terminal, and immediately it comes up the crash report message window. I tried all these things, without success:

- uninstalled and reinstalled the program several times (remove and auto purge).
- uninstalled the flash plugin.
- tried to launch in safe mode.
- tried to create another user but I couldn't access the firefox's managing profile window since it crashes immediately.
- tried another user on linux.
- installed Chromium and Qupzilla, none of them worked (same immediate crash).

When I received the message that there are no more updates for 16.10, I moved to the 17.04 and then also 17.10. Same results.
Then I decided to wipe out everything, I used a live cd with mate-ubuntu and also Xubuntu (both 17.10), deleted the linux partitions and reinstalled everything. Again the same error.

The only thing “new” is that during the installation process I received a webkit2gtk error, but without any further detail.
I launched from terminal the command firefox -jsconsole, but it lasts a couple of seconds and then it crashes. I just managed to screenshot some errors:

- Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///usr/lib/firefox/chrome.manifest'
- 1511000182748 Toolkit.telemetry ERROR ClientID::getCachedClientIS - invalid client id type in preferences, resetting
- JavaScript 1.6's for-each-in loops are deprecated; consider using ES6 for-of instead
- TypeError: can't access dead object

Some of these errors are repeated several times with small changes.

The thing that really sounds strange to me is that even after a full reinstall of the whole operative system, there is no way to make firefox works.

I installed the live cd in a virtual machine, and firefox open correctly.

I'm running out of ideas!
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you launch firefox from a terminal window, and copy/paste the output after it 'crashes'. It's not clear what the 'same error' you refer to is.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @mikewhatever: as soon as I'm at home I'll do that, but the "same error" statement is about the error found in the console, not in the terminal window.

Comment: @N0rbert: the PC has 2 GB of RAM and plenty of space in the HD

Comment: Run `top` or `htop`, then start firefox. I think browsers crash when RAM is over.

Comment: @mikewhatever: from the terminal:$ firefox
ExcpetionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 1097
ExcpetionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExcpetionHandler::WaitForContueSignal waiting for continue signal...
$

Comment: @N0rbert: thank you for the suggestion, Libre Office works without problem, and it uses RAM. I'll try your idea.